# Looping over Temp table records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my SQL script

```
SELECT * 
INTO #Temp 
FROM Users 
WHERE AccountCode = 'Basic'

DECLARE @userId VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @iterator INT = 0
DECLARE @fullName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @generatedAccountCode VARCHAR(50)

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temp)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @userId = USERID 
    FROM #Temp

    SET @iterator = @iterator + 1
    SET @generatedAccountCode = 'PMT' + CAST(@iterator AS VARCHAR)
    SET @fullName = (Select u.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + u.LASTNAME FROM Users u where USERID = @userId)

    INSERT INTO Accounts(AccountCode, FullName, DateCreated)
    VALUES (@generatedAccountCode, @fullName, GETDATE());

    UPDATE Users 
    SET AccountCode = @generatedAccountCode
    WHERE USERID = @userId 

    DELETE #Temp 
    WHERE USERID = @userId
END
```

Current state of database: `#Temp` table consists records of users with no `AccountCode`. For all these users, `AccountCode` is set to "Basic" in table `Users`.

**What I am trying to do**

I want to loop over all records in my #Temp table. I am generating a random `AccountCode`. First `AccountCode` is going to be generated PMT1 then next time we loop over it is going to be generated as PMT2. Once this `AccountCode` is created in `Accounts` table, I then want to set that `AccountCode` in `Users` table to that generatedAccountCode. So this way each of these users have a unique Account code in Accounts table.

When I run this script, it generates the account codes in table Users in the manner how I expect it to be in a serialized manner (PMT1, PMT2) but in `Accounts` table account does not go in serialized manner. What am I doing wrong?

This is going to be a one time run script and after that I am going to have my API changes so we don't have to run this script ever again.

Comment: You don't need a loop here. Either use ROW_NUMBER or a tally table. Also, you have varchar with no size. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: I am not even sure how to get started with ROW_NUMBER @SeanLange and which varchar you are referencing to ?

Comment: ohhh I see...are you talking about when I m casting iterator to varchar. I would change that.

Comment: The varchar in your loop. You cast your iterator to a varchar. Do you know the default size? Do you know that the default size can change depending on usage? Be precise.

Comment: `CAST(@iterator AS varchar)`

Comment: yes I got that @SeanLange

Comment: I would be wary of storing the full name like that. I would prefer to keep them separated and stored in only one location. Otherwise your full name data is stale as soon as your query is completed.

Comment: Why do you care about the order of the accounts table anyway? So long as the correct records are stored? What exactly is ending up in your accounts table which isn't desirable?

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid loop:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(AccountCode NVARCHAR(100), UserId INT);

--single run only(AccountCode is not stable sort)
MERGE INTO Accounts trg
USING (Select  AccountCode = CONCAT('PMT', ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 1/0))
          ,FullName = u.FIRSTNAME + ' ' + u.LASTNAME
          ,DateCreated = GETDATE()
          ,u.UserId
        From   Users u
        where AccountCode = 'Basic') src
ON trg.AccountCode = src.AccountCode
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
   INSERT (AccountCode, FullName, DateCreated)
   VALUES (src.AccountCode, src.FullName, src.DateCreated)
OUTPUT inserted.AccountCode, src.UserId
INTO #temp;

Update u
set AccountCode = t.AccountCode
FROM users u
JOIN #temp t
  ON u.UserId = t.UserId;
```

**[db<>fiddle  demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3e30211e0709b0d0e0d5ebb8e4e8c29)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without looping with something like this :

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#Temp') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Temp 

SELECT 
    USERID
,   FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME FullName
,   'PMT' + CAST( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY USERID) AS VARCHAR(50) ) generatedAccountCode
INTO #Temp 
FROM 
    Users 
WHERE 
    AccountCode = 'Basic'

INSERT INTO Accounts(AccountCode, FullName, DateCreated)
SELECT 
    generatedAccountCode
,   FullName
,   GETDATE()
FROM 
    #Temp 

UPDATE u 
SET 
    AccountCode = generatedAccountCode
FROM 
    Users u 
JOIN #Temp tmp ON Tmp.USERID = u.USERID
```